# Is cudaMemcpy2D limited in Size?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have been using cudaMemcpy2D to send a 2D array from 20 * 20 char values to my kernel, however when I want to try to send an array of 20 * 30 there is an error appearing.

The code for these lines is the following :

I define the constants like this :

```
//Define for 2D arrays
#define TEXTSIZE 20
#define NUMBERTEXT 30
```

I define my textPitch like this

```
size_t pitch_text;
```

I initialise my array like this :

```
char text[NUMBERTEXT][TEXTSIZE] = {{'A','A','B','C','B','B','C','A','B','A','A','B','B','A','A','A','C','A','A','B'},\ ... }};
```

I make my cudamalloc like this :

```
gpuErrchk(cudaMallocPitch( (void**)&d_text, &pitch_text, NUMBERTEXT * sizeof(char), TEXTSIZE));
```

CudaMemcpy2D is initialised like this :

```
gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy2D(d_text, pitch_text, text, TEXTSIZE * sizeof(char), TEXTSIZE * sizeof(char),NUMBERTEXT, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

and the error received is the following :

```
    GPUassert: invalid argument ../2D.cu 212
```

Error at line 212 is basically the CudaMemcpy2D line.

Is there any better way to send large 2D array to the GPU in Global Memory ? Notice that the code is working fine if I use 20 * 20 Arrays.

Thank you

Comment: soo it is `char TEXT[NUMBERTEXT][TEXTSIZE]`. am I right? or they are different constants?

Comment: It's not limited in size to 20 x 20.  You have made a mistake in how you are using the call but you haven't provided enough information to tell what is wrong.  Please provide a more complete definition of what you are doing including defintion of all constants, all variable definitions, and the complete cudaMallocPitch and cudaMemcpy calls.  note that you are defining a `char TEXT[][]` but passing a lowercase variable `text`, so I don't think that would work as written.

Comment: @RobertCrovella so the place of the sizes in `cudaMemcpy2D` is right?

Comment: @SorooshBateni  I think so.  In C, a multidimensional array is subscripted as `array[rows][columns]`, where `columns` gives the width of the array in elements.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have updated my post with all the variables I was using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your call to [cudaMallocPitch](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g80d689bc903792f906e49be4a0b6d8db) (not in cudaMemcpy2D).  You reversed the height and width parameters.  In C, the doubly subscripted array is declared like `array[rows][columns]` where `columns` (i.e. the 2nd subscript) refers to the width.

To fix this, instead of this:

```
cudaMallocPitch( (void**)&d_text, &pitch_text, NUMBERTEXT * sizeof(char), TEXTSIZE);
```

Do this:

```
cudaMallocPitch( (void**)&d_text, &pitch_text, TEXTSIZE * sizeof(char), NUMBERTEXT);
```

The last parameter to cudaMallocPitch is the `Requested pitched allocation height`, i.e. the rows parameter.

**EDIT**: To respond to further questions in the comments, here is/was the code I was using for test purposes. Specifically for the question about size of the text array, I cannot reproduce a segfault with this code for the sizes up to 90x120 or so.  Therefore I think a segfault is probably a separate issue.

my test code (does not segfault):

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Define for 2D arrays
#define TEXTSIZE 90
#define NUMBERTEXT 120

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

int main(){


  size_t pitch_text;
  char *d_text;
  char text[NUMBERTEXT][TEXTSIZE];

  cudaMallocPitch( (void**)&d_text, &pitch_text, TEXTSIZE * sizeof(char), NUMBERTEXT);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMallocPitch error");
  cudaMemcpy2D(d_text, pitch_text, text, TEXTSIZE * sizeof(char), TEXTSIZE * sizeof(char),NUMBERTEXT, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy2D error");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That actually make sense ! Thanks for the help !

Comment: although once, you get over 20 * 70 array of char you get a segmentation fault.

Comment: I wrote a simple program using the bits of code you provided.  It does not segfault for larger values like 20 x70 or 90 x 80. Have you isolated the line at which the segfault is occurring?  You may want to post a new question if you need help with it.

Comment: Isn't it related to this subject ? because it gives me a segfault when I change NUMBERTEXT to 120 and it seems that the problem line is cudaMallocPitch().

Comment: I think it is probably some other problem besided the swap of NUMBERTEXT and TEXTSIZE error that you made.  SO works best in my opinion if we have focused questions and answeres.  It's not well designed for back and forth dialog as you work through debugging your code.  That is why I suggested starting a new question.  Regardless, I have posted a simple code that I used to test my work.  If you have a problem with segfault, my suggestion is to look at my code on your machine and see if it segfaults.  If it does not, try reducing your code down to an equally simple example.